# Null Pointer exception in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asynchronous

I am facing NullPointerException in below code as it is happening very rarely and I tried to debug to replicate the issue but no luck. Can anybody help me what can cause NullPointerException here.

```
private static void MyTaskCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        var worker = (AsyncErrorDelegate)((AsyncResult)res).AsyncDelegate;
        var async = (AsyncOperation)res.AsyncState;
        worker.EndInvoke(res);
        lock (IsAsyncOpOccuring)
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
        var completedArgs = new AsyncCompletedEventArgs(null, false, null);
        async.PostOperationCompleted(e => OnTaskCompleted((AsyncCompletedEventArgs)e), completedArgs);
    }
```

Null Pointer exception is reported at 
var async = (AsyncOperation)res.AsyncState;

Code from where I am invoking it

```
 var context = HttpContext.Current;
        AsyncErrorDelegate bkWorker = SendErrorMail;
        AsyncCallback completedCallback = MyTaskCompletedCallback;
        lock (IsAsyncOpOccuring)
        {
            if (IsBusy)
            {
                //Do we need to do something if repeated async getting call in case of error occuring at same time by different users.

            }

            AsyncOperation async = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
            bkWorker.BeginInvoke(context,completedCallback, async);
            IsBusy = true;
        }
```

Comment: do you actually mean a "null pointer" exception? or is it a `NullReferenceException` ? pointer != reference (well, not strictly)

Comment: K; now that you've edited that: how do you do the `BeginInvoke` ? is there any chance you're simply **passing in a null state** ? Also: for info, the handling of `IsBusy` is dangerous in two different ways: if `EndInvoke` reports an exception, it'll never be marked as not busy, and you can't have more than one async task without corrupting that. Personally, I'd use an interlocked counter, but that might just be me.

Comment: I have updated the above code for the begin invoke.You rightly pointed IsBusy can be dangerous...will update it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Null Pointer exception is reported at `var async = (AsyncOperation)res.AsyncState;`

We can logically deduce that this is not actually the case.

If the line before worked, we know that `res` is not null. `AsyncState` is `object`, so no custom operators are involved here, which means the cast is thus a type-check - which can either return `null` (without erroring), or can raise an invalid-cast exception.

If you are seeing a `NullReferenceException`, that leaves 2 options:

- `res` is null and it is the *line above* that is erroring (which: we shouldn't actually expect - that will not happen)
- the error is actually coming from `EndInvoke`, the line *after*

(the exact line often gets slightly confused when an exception is involved).

I suggest you add logging between each, to track what is happening. I also suggest you explicitly `try` around the `EndInvoke`, since that can throw exceptions (it re-throws any exception from the async operation).

In the more general case, a third option would have been:

- `AsyncOperation` is a `struct`, and `AsyncState` is `null`

However, in this case we can rule that out by deduction, because if `AsyncOperation` were a `struct`, the following would **never** box to `null` (only an empty `AsyncOperation?` would box to `null`):

```
AsyncOperation async = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
bkWorker.BeginInvoke(context,completedCallback, async);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should

`var async = (AsyncOperation)asyncResult.AsyncState;`

not be

`var async = (AsyncOperation)res.AsyncState;`

?

Comment: That would be a compiler error. I guess the sample code is just inconsistent.

Comment: @usr not if `asyncResult` is a static field

Comment: @MarcGravell although turned out not to be true, that was a good idea.